# text does not wrap to next line

Tags: html, css

I have this section in a form where the content does not wrap to the next line in a list-item. How can I get it to overlap the width of the div content

The second line mostly where it says **Security Question two**

[image]

My HTML & CSS:

```
<ul class="o-pf-list o-pf-list--mg-left col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <!-- o-pf-list--mg-left -->
    <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="password">Password</label> <div class="pull-left"> ******** </div> </li>
    <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="security">Security Question one</label> <div class="o-pf-text-align">Mothers maiden name? </div> </li>
    <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="security">Security Question two</label> <div class="o-pf-text-align">Name of the pre-primary school you attended? </div> </li>
    <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="ip_hostnames">Allowed IPs &amp; hostnames</label> <div class="pull-left"> All (no restrictions) </div> </li>
    <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="allowed_countries">Allowed countries</label> <div class="pull-left"> All (no restrictions) </div> </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
.o-pf-list {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.o-pf-list--mg-left {
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.o-pf-list__item {
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

.o-pf-text-align {
    position: relative;
    top: -12px;
    float: right;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: could you make a jsFiddle, or use the SO code snippets? Thanks

Comment: grid system in bootstrap in based on a 12 columns width. Try changing all your col-md-8 to have a sum total of 12

Comment: Sure will do that.

Comment: The outer column is a 12 column. This is just the snippet. The form is wrapped in a col-lg-6 and I have a nested col-lg-8

Comment: @N.Ivanov here is a codepen of the issue. [form](https://codepen.io/CrispianAnyster/pen/JyvryW)

Comment: You can use flex to fixed it check answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only bootstrap way, just add `col-md-4 col-lg-4` to div which coming in `li` like below.

```
      <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="password">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4"> ******** </div>
  </li>
```

```css
.o-pf-list {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.o-pf-list--mg-left {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.o-pf-list__item {
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.o-pf-text-align {
  /* position: relative;
    top: -12px;
    float: right;
    line-height: 0; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="o-pf-list o-pf-list--mg-left col-md-8 col-lg-8">
  <!-- o-pf-list--mg-left -->
  <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="password">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4"> ******** </div>
  </li>
  <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="security">Security Question one</label>
    <div class="o-pf-text-align col-md-4 col-lg-4">Mothers maiden name? </div>
  </li>
  <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="security">Security Question two</label>
    <div class="o-pf-text-align col-md-4 col-lg-4">Name of the pre-primary school you attended? </div>
  </li>
  <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="ip_hostnames">Allowed IPs &amp; hostnames</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4"> All (no restrictions) </div>
  </li>
  <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="allowed_countries">Allowed countries</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4"> All (no restrictions) </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[Bootstrap way](https://jsfiddle.net/0qfe6gzr/)**

You can use flex to get it change css part

**[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Lokeshg27/pen/vJjeRj)**

```
   .o-pf-list__item {
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .o-pf-list__item label,
    div {
      flex: 1;
    }

    .o-pf-text-align {
     /* position: relative; */
     /* top: -12px; */
     /* float: right; */
     /* line-height: 0; */
   }

   .o-pf-list--mg-left {
      margin-left: 0px;
   }
```

```css
.o-pf-list {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.o-pf-list--mg-left {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.o-pf-list__item {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.o-pf-list__item label,
div {
  flex: 1;
}

.o-pf-text-align {
  /* position: relative; */
  /* top: -12px; */
  /* float: right; */
  /* line-height: 0; */
}
```

```html
<ul class="o-pf-list o-pf-list--mg-left col-md-8 col-lg-8">
  <!-- o-pf-list--mg-left -->
  <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="password">Password</label>
    <div class="pull-left"> ******** </div>
  </li>
  <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="security">Security Question one</label>
    <div class="o-pf-text-align">Mothers maiden name? </div>
  </li>
  <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="security">Security Question two</label>
    <div class="o-pf-text-align">Name of the pre-primary school you attended? </div>
  </li>
  <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="ip_hostnames">Allowed IPs &amp; hostnames</label>
    <div class="pull-left"> All (no restrictions) </div>
  </li>
  <li class="o-pf-list__item"> <label class="col-md-8 col-lg-8" for="allowed_countries">Allowed countries</label>
    <div class="pull-left"> All (no restrictions) </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your second example word. Just some more tweaks I need to do then it is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Sure will do. Thanks again.